# Java/Tomcat: how to handle WebSocket setup completion

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, websocket, jsr356

I have the following scenario: few Tomcat instances with the same application need to connect between each other on startup. For connection between servers, WebSockets (JSR-356) are used.
When Tomcat has started, I need to initiate the establishment with another server.

How can I handle the most correctly, that internal WebSockets mechanism is up and I can start using WebSockets?

Application is based on Spring 4.

I tried this [Execute method on startup in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring), this [How to add a hook to the application context initialization event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event) and this [Tomcat after Startup Event with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747525/tomcat-after-startup-event-with-spring) .

All this approaches are cool but seems that on that moments WebSockets are still not ready to be used. 
Next exception is thrown:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed    
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:373)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:201)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:222)
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at sun.nio.ch.PendingFuture.get(PendingFuture.java:197)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.processResponse(WsWebSocketContainer.java:599)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:343)
```

For now, as a workaround, I use 3 seconds delays in WebServlet's init() method before establishing the connection but it is kinda hack I would like to avoid.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why WebSockets? You need to wait for the connector to be up to use them. The connector will come up once the application is ready. The application is ready once its startup hooks have run. Oops.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I tried to initiate websockets connection when application context is up but no luck. Could you please describe more deeply how to handle that connector is up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it just by setting connection establishment into separate thread.
Without separate thread, it blocks the continue of Tomcat startup.
Hope it will help one day to somebody.