# Establishing websocket connection between embedded Tomcat 8.0.3 and tomcat 7.0.53

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a simple websocket client in Java. I have an embedded tomcat 8.0.3 server using springboot. The client is trying to connect to a server on another machine running tomcat 7.0.53. However I get the following error after trying to establish a websocket:

```
2014-07-02 11:13:56.861  INFO 13656 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketConnectionManager     : Connecting to WebSocket at ws://54.213.202.109:8880/wspoc/ws/10

2014-07-02 11:14:01.885 ERROR 13656 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketConnectionManager     : Failed to connect

javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.connectToServer(WsWebSocketContainer.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:125)

    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:122)

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient.doHandshakeInternal(StandardWebSocketClient.java:135)

    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.AbstractWebSocketClient.doHandshake(AbstractWebSocketClient.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketConnectionManager.openConnection(WebSocketConnectionManager.java:139)

    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.ConnectionManagerSupport.startInternal(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:129)

    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.WebSocketConnectionManager.startInternal(WebSocketConnectionManager.java:122)

    at org.springframework.web.socket.client.ConnectionManagerSupport.start(ConnectionManagerSupport.java:118)
    at com.hp.fucms.impl.TopoRestController.test(TopoRestController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:676)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

this is my client code

```
            WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
            TopoWebSocketHandler handler = new TopoWebSocketHandler();
            String pathId = "ws://54.213.202.109:8880/wspoc/ws/10";
            WebSocketConnectionManager manager = new WebSocketConnectionManager(client, handler,pathId);
            manager.start();
```

And my `handler` class:

```
public class TopoWebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {private WebSocketSession session;

        @Override
        public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session,
            TextMessage message) throws Exception{

                System.out.println("Message "+message.getPayload());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception{
                session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hello"));
        }
}
```

Is this some issue with using the `embedded server` vs `standalone server` for `websockets`?

Comment: I have quite similar issue and the same exception. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380364/java-tomcat-how-to-handle-websocket-setup-completion . Temporarely workarounded it, doing the connection in 3 seconds after server is up (in separate thread).

Comment: btw, your stack trace is not full. see the line 351 of http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-websocket/8.0.3/org/apache/tomcat/websocket/WsWebSocketContainer.java . What type of exception you have (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | SSLException | EOFException | TimeoutException) ?

Comment: Just starting the connection in separate thread is enough, no need dirty 3 seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

We resolved it to a proxy issue, and the problem was seemingly unrelated to the nature of the embedded server/standalone server connection.