# Spring Boot - Wait for web server to start

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application I need to wait until the (default Tomcat) web server is fully initialized and ready to take traffic before I send messages to other applications telling them to send HTTP requests to me (specifically a monitoring system that hits my `/health`).

I've tried putting the logic that sends messages to other applications in a `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` but it's still too early. The other applications try to make requests to me and fail.  Right now I've put a delay in the `onApplicationEvent` and that works but it's hacky and racy.

I've also tried adding a `ServletContextInitializer` but that fired even earlier.

I'm assuming that I'll need to use a Tomcat API but I wanted to see if there was something in the Boot API for this.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4747639/283084? Additionally maybe you can hide your app behind an LB and the LB won't take your app into it's pool until a request to `/health` returns HTTP OK (200).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to send the message once `SpringApplication.run()` has returned. This method won't return until Tomcat (or any other supported embedded container) is fully started and listening on the configured port(s). However, while this is simple, it's not a very neat approach as it mixes the concerns of your main configuration class and some of your application's runtime logic.

Instead, you can use a [`SpringApplicationRunListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplicationRunListener.html). `finished()` will not be called until Tomcat is fully started and listening on the configured port.

Create a file named `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` listing your run listener. For example:

```
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener=com.example.MyRunListener
```

Create your run listener with the required constructor and implement `SpringApplicationRunListener`. For example:

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListener;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;

public class MyRunListener implements SpringApplicationRunListener {

    public MyRunListener(SpringApplication application, String[] args) { }

    @Override
    public void starting() { }

    @Override
    public void environmentPrepared(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) { }

    @Override
    public void contextPrepared(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) { }

    @Override
    public void contextLoaded(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) { }

    @Override
    public void started(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        // Send message; Tomcat is running and listening on the configured port(s)
    }

    @Override
    public void running(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) { }

    @Override
    public void failed(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, Throwable exception) { }
```

Comment: Works great.  I created another interface that the interested beans can implement and my `SpringApplicationRunListener` pulls them out of the context and calls them, so the logic can stay in the relevant bean(s).

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all. The finished() method is called almost immediately and certainly well before the application is up and running.

Comment: @onnoweb I can't see how that would happen as the finished method is called at the end of `SpringApplication.run` processing. Perhaps you can ask a question of your own with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) that shows finished being called earlier than expected.

Comment: I narrowed down my issue: ApplicationReadyEvent gets fired just before Tomcat is up and running. Using a CommandLineRunner instead of listening for ApplicationReadyEvent fixed my issue.

Comment: This interface has been updated; newer implementations should now use the `running` method.

Comment: Good point, @IanMc. I've edited my answer to align with Spring Boot 2.x.

Answer (score 8):

Since Spring Boot 1.3.0  this can also be accomplished by implementing `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>`

example:

```
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>, Ordered {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        //do stuff now that application is ready
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the accepted answer, you can create a file named `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` listing your `ApplicationListener`. For example:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=com.example.MyApplicationListener
```

however, in my case, I only needed this listener to run under a specific profile

so I added the following property to `application-<profile_name>.properties`

```
context.listener.classes=com.example.MyApplicationListener
```