# Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE ApplicationReadyEvent not found

Tags: spring-boot

I am reading Spring Boot reference (version 1.2.3-RELEASE) and in point
22.4 Application events and listeners point 4 states:

"An ApplicationReadyEvent is sent after the refresh and any related callbacks
have been processed to indicate the application is ready to service requests."

So I tried:

```
SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(LearnSpringBootApplication.class);
app.addListeners(new ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>() {
```

...

but it cannot find the ApplicationReadyEvent. Has it been removed ?
If so - is there any equivalent for it ?

I found this post here:

[Spring Boot - Wait for web server to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240403/spring-boot-wait-for-web-server-to-start)

but was wondering if there is another way?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/53ca15b478bca8e405821b90216021bc388c4638/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.java

Comment: `ApplicationReadyEvent` is new in 1.3.0 so I would guess that you were inadvertently looking at the wrong docs. The docs for 1.2.x are here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners