# Springboot: need to be informed/notified when Web-Server is Up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am writing a Springboot application embedding Tomcat as a Web Server.

At startup, some of my threads are ready *(and so start doing their job)* **before** Tomcat is. For many contraints I have, I want that these threads **do nothing before Tomcat is ready**

But I don't know how to decided to block/unblock my threads; to do so, I need to be informed of the Tomcat status. Is there:

- a way to ask: `isWebServerStarted()`?
- or a way to be notified asynchronously by a message saying: `WEB_SERVER_IS_STARTED`?

Thank you for help

> FYI, I don't want to declare a kind of "private ReST endpoint" that my
>   application could try to reach in order to guess whether the webserver
>   is ready

Comment: Looks like it's the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240403/spring-boot-wait-for-web-server-to-start

Answer (score 0):

Go with a `ServletContextListener`. Annotate your class with `@WebListener` and tell spring configuration about this listener by adding `@ServletComponentScan` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Createn an application event

```
applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
```

And implement `ApplicationListener` in bean class to listen events.