# Process existing files on startup in a folder with VFS2

Tags: java, tomcat, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I have multiple FileListeners that process all the files which are inserted in remote folders using the org.apache.commons.vfs2 library.

Sometimes I have to stop Tomcat, so if new files are inserted in the folders, they will not be processed although I start my WebService after they have been inserted.

I have been doing some research and the following URLs[1][2] force me to hard code the folder's location and I don't know how well It would work with multiple Listeners at the same time processing.

Is there a better way to configure the FileListener on startup? Thanks.

1. [Tomcat after Startup Event with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747525/tomcat-after-startup-event-with-spring)
2. [Callback on tomcat server startup complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390818/callback-on-tomcat-server-startup-complete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue with not a beautiful way. I create on startup a new thread in one webapp , sleep it , and then after Tomcat startup, process the existing files.